# как заменить путь в классе к json файлу, если он лежит на сервере?

Tags: java, android, json, http, gson

Имею класс, который составляет **ArrayList** , забирая файл **.json** из папки **/assets** внутри приложения.

Как забрать файл из интернета? Где и что переписать в классе нужно?

Например, если файл **.json** лежит по пути **http:// mysite.ru/index.json**

public class ArrayListMain {

```
    //private static final String TAG = Log.buildTag(Directory.class);
    private static List<Station> stations = null;

    private static Map<String, Station> stationIndex = new HashMap<>();

    public static void loadStations(final Context context) {
        stations = new ArrayList<>();

        final AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

        String paths[] = new String[0];
        try {
            paths = assetManager.list("stations");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "error loading stations", e);
            return;
        }

        for (String path : paths) {
            if (!path.endsWith(".json"))
                continue;
            final Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Station>>() {}.getType();
            List<Station> chunk = null;
            try {
                chunk = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("stations/" + path), "UTF-8"), listType);
                stations.addAll(chunk);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "error loading station: %s", e, path);
            }
        }

        Station.sort(stations);

        indexStations(stations);

    }

    private static void indexStations(final List<Station> stations) {
        stationIndex.clear();

        for (Station station : stations) {
            stationIndex.put(station.getStationUrl(), station);
        }
    }

    public static List<Station> getStations() {
        return stations;
    }

    public static Station getStation(final String url) {
        return stationIndex.get(url);
    }
}
```

**p.s: был дан ответ, который почему-то удалили и в добавок ко всему, заминусовали сам вопрос. Хотел обратиться к человеку, который оставлял ответ здесь. Не мог бы он изложить еще раз его. Иначе здесь происходит какая-то вакханалия и модераторы творят что хотят...**

Comment: А где ответ, который был здесь час назад? Какова причина его удаления???

Comment: Ответ был автором удалён. Почему - одному богу известно. Я его восстановил, но автор может опять удалить, так что спешите прочитать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб если честно, я не помню.. Возможно, случайно или хотел сделать что-то другое. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим, у вас есть сайт `https://mysite.com`, у него по пути `/json` доступны нужные вам json-файлы. Например: `https://mysite.com/json/json_0.json`, `https://mysite.com/json/json_1.json` и так далее. То есть вы знаете префикс и у вас есть список имён этих файлов (либо вы его можете откуда-то получить). Задача очень тривиальна: просто получить содержимое ответа сетевого запроса, а потом его обработать. Не стал бы советовать делать так, как я ниже покажу в примере (потому что он специфичен лишь для кода, который вы привели в вопросе). Лучше подумайте над архитектурой, что откуда должно вызываться, какие библиотеки станете использовать.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String baseUrl = "http://mysite.com/json/";

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Формируете ссылки, итерируетесь по файлам на сайте
    // своим способом; это лишь пример
    String url = baseUrl + "json_" + i + ".json";
    List<Station> chunk = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream()), listType);
    stations.addAll(chunk);
}
```

Таким способом лучше не стоит получать содержимое ответа на свой запрос в сеть, но объяснение этого — гораздо более обширная тема, и её нет смысла включать в этот ответ. На конкретном вашем примере из вопроса я показал, как можно обрабатывать лежащие в сети, а не в ассетах, файлы. На ваш вопрос в текущей формулировке, я думаю, что ответил.